# Is immutability very worthwhile when there is no concurrency?

Tags: immutability, semantics, collections, mutable

It seems that thread-safety is always/often mentioned as the main benefit of using immutable types and especially collections.

I have a situation where I would like to make sure that a method will not modify a dictionary of strings (which are immutable in C#). I’d like to constrain things as much as possible.

However I am not sure whether adding a dependency to a new package (Microsoft Immutable Collections) is worth it. Performance is not a big issue either.

So I guess my question is whether immutable collections are *strongly* advised for when there are no hard performance requirements and there are no thread safety issues? Consider that value semantics (as in my example) might or might not be a requirement as well.

Comment: Concurrent modification need not mean threads. Just look at the aptly named `ConcurrentModificationException` which is usually caused by the same thread mutating the collection in the same thread, in the body of a `foreach` loop over the same collection.

Comment: I mean you aren't wrong, but that is different than what OP is asking.  That exception is thrown because modification during enumeration is not allowed.  Using a ConcurrentDictionary, for example, would still have this error.

Comment: Maybe you should also ask yourself the opposite question: when is mutability worthwhile?

Comment: In Java, if mutability affects `hashCode()` or `equals(Object)` result being changed, it may cause errors when using `Collections` (for example, in a `HashSet` the object was stored in a "bucket" and after mutating it should go to another one).

Comment: @Giorgio mutability is worthwhile when you want your code to run on a CPU, instead of running on abstract mathematics. (Or you can get an abstract mathematics simulator for your CPU - the approach some languages take)

Comment: @immibis: What do you mean exactly? Any program we want to run has to run on a CPU.

Comment: @Giorgio - that's the point!

Comment: @DavorŽdralo As far as high level languages' abstractions go, pervasive immutability is rather tame. It is just a natural extension of the very common abstraction (present even in C) of creating, and silently discarding, "temporary values". Perhaps you mean to say it's an inefficient way to use a CPU, but that argument has flaws too: Mutability-happy but dynamic languages often perform worse than immutable-only but static languages, partly because there are some clever (but ultimately quite simple) tricks to optimize programs juggling immutable data: Linear types, deforestation, etc.

Comment: @delnan: Good points. Often there is little or no efficiency loss at all. E.g. compare using a mutable variable in an imperative loop to using an immutable accumulator variable in a tail-recursive function: time and resource consumption is probably very similar but immutable variables offer the advantages explained in KChaloux' answer.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Immutability simplifies the amount of information you need to track mentally when reading code later**. For mutable variables, and *especially* mutable class members, it's very hard to know what state they will be in at the specific line you're reading about, without running through the code with a debugger. Immutable data is *easy to reason about* - it will always be the same. If you want to change it, you need to make a new value.

I would honestly prefer making things immutable **by default**, and then changing them to mutable where it's proven that they need to be, whether this means you need the performance, or an algorithm you have doesn't make sense for immutability.

Comment: +1 Concurrency is simultaneous mutation, but mutation that spreads over time can be just as hard to reason about

Comment: To expand on this: a function that relies on a mutable variable can be thought of as taking an extra hidden argument, which is the current value of the mutable variable. Any function which changes a mutable variable can likewise be thought of as producing an extra return value, i.e. the new value of the mutable state. When looking at a piece of code you have no idea if it depends on or changes mutable state so you have to find out and then keep track of the changes mentally. This also introduces coupling between any two pieces of code that share mutable state, and coupling is bad.

Comment: *"it's very hard to know"*... is it really *that* hard? People have managed to do this for decades now.

Comment: @Mehrdad People also managed to crank out large programs in assembly for decades. Then we did a couple of decades of C.

Comment: @Mehrdad it's nice to know what is intended to happen to a collection parameter just by looking at the signature. Otherwise (theoretically) you need to write an extra unit test, checking that a collection did not change after calling a function.

Comment: @Den: I don't see why you can't have your cake and eat it too. Why not just take C++'s approach? The types are mutable, but you can receive parameters of those types by copy or by a read-only reference. That gives you immutability of the caller's variables without tying your hand behind your back for all instances of that type.

Comment: @Doval: I don't really feel like the kind of productivity gained by moving from assembly to C or C++ is even remotely in the same ballpark as the kind gained from going from mutable to immutable types; do you?

Comment: @Mehrdad Copying whole objects isn't a good option when the objects are large. I don't see why the order of magnitude involved in the improvement matters. Would you turn down a 20% improvement (note: arbitrary number) in productivity simply because it wasn't a triple-digit improvement? Immutability is a sane *default*; you *can* stray from it, but you need a reason.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, it can be very hard to know. Even if you check carefully through *all* the code that is there now, you can't assume it will behave in the future.  Your method accesses a mutable field, it also calls other class methods.  Each of those other methods could modify the member.  Even if you check all the existing code now and don't miss anything, somebody could change one of those methods and break your code.   The mutable member means that everybody writing code which accesses or modifies it has to check all the other code.  That is inefficient and does not scale.

Comment: If the field is immutable, suddenly you don't have to worry about (or know) the internal implementation of those other methods; you know your code is safe.

Comment: "I don't really feel like the kind of productivity gained by moving from assembly to C or C++ is even remotely in the same ballpark as the kind gained from going from mutable to immutable types; do you?": I attended a course on Scala programming in which only immutable variables were used for all programming assignments. I experienced a noticeable increase in productivity.

Comment: @Giorgio Scala made me realize just how infrequently you need to even make a value mutable. Whenever I use that language, I make everything a `val`, and only on very, very rare occasions do I find that I need to change something into a `var`. A lot of the 'variables' I define in any given language are just there to hold a value that stores the result of some computation, and doesn't need to be updated.

Comment: @KChaloux: Exactly. You need mutability only for optimization (and not as a means to hold intermediate results of a computation) and to store state. You do not need state **that** often. And you should not optimize too early: if it is fast enough, use immutable variables.

Comment: @Doval: Yeah, that's my point. I *would* turn down a 20% improvement. Why? Because immutability doesn't come for free -- there's a price tag: it makes the code more inefficient. So there has to be a justification for you to pay that cost, and *a 20% productivity improvement isn't a justification for me to make my code slower*.

Comment: @itsbruce: I don't see how it can "not scale"? Like I said, people have been doing this for decades, so obviously, this *does* scale. It might be a bit more work sometimes, but it's not like people can't do it. And mutability brings about efficiency too.

Comment: @KChaloux: Use `const` in C++ and you'll realize the same thing: most variables can be `const`.

Comment: @Giorgio: Er, I didn't ask if it was "noticeable", I asked if it was "even remotely in the same ballpark". A 20% increase is "noticeable" but not even remotely in the same ballpark.

Comment: @Mehrdad Let's suppose I take that at face value (I don't) - choosing mutability is still an optimization and you shouldn't optimize prematurely. But it's not clear that immutability has serious performance implications. In terms of big-O, the worst that happens is usually going from O(1) to O(logN) random accesses. But if part of your algorithm is O(N), then it'll still be O(N) after switching to the immutable version. Second, mutability can hurt caching - see [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). Third, parallelism is hopelessly difficult with shared mutable data.

Comment: @Mehrdad Re: scaling, mutability doesn't scale because the more it spreads, the harder it is to keep track of. Pure functional code, on the other hand, can be composed freely without an ever-growing heap of implicit state changes to keep track of.

Comment: @Doval: I love that you actually tried asymptotic time complexity analysis. Your analysis is wrong though. An O(N) algorithm can (must?) easily become O(N log N) with immutability. It is no longer O(N) like you claim, and a log N factor is not something that you can gloss over like that. (Think of an algorithm like BWT; how can you *possibly* claim it will stay efficient with immutable arrays?)

Comment: @Doval: In theory yeah, but I'm saying in practice much of the code you're using directly or indirectly every day is mutable and it's already scaled, so that argument isn't so convincing.

Comment: @Mehrdad No, that simply does not follow. I'm saying the cost of scaling up increases with the size of the code base with mutable code. Pointing to some code base of size `N` doesn't disprove that; it merely shows that someone could afford the cost of scaling to that size.

Comment: @Mehrdad: 'If it was "even remotely in the same ballpark".': definitely yes.

Comment: @Giorgio: Could you give me a ballpark number then? How many times faster were you? 10x?

Comment: @Mehrdad: 10x is a lot. I would say 3x considering less development time and much much less debugging time.

Comment: @Doval: It doesn't disprove that, but it does prove what (doesn't) works in practice doesn't necessarily match what you expect to (not) work in theory.

Comment: @Giorgio: Thanks, 3x is pretty impressive. Not convinced it's close to the same ballpark though. If I had to switch from C++ to assembly, I think it would take me at least an order of magnitude or even two orders more time, not just twice or three times as long.

Comment: @Doval: So, any thoughts on the log N factor?

Comment: @Mehrdad Like I said, it's still a non-issue if you don't actually have performance problems, or you're not in the critical section of code, or if you can make any use of parallelism. In order to recommend mutability on a performance basis you first have to establish you have a performance problem and then prove that a mutable solution performs better. Until then, it's a premature optimization. I won't be responding after this comment since this discussion has turned quite lengthy and lengthy discussions should be taken to chat.

Comment: @Doval: Yeah, well what about when you **do** have a performance problem?! The fact that your best rebuttal is "well, *if* it's not a problem then I'll just ignore it" is my entire point here. Parallelism isn't a magic bullet. One machine only contains so many CPUs (say, 8), so it's not like you actually *will* necessarily have the parallelism you need. But parallelizing beyond that is *freaking hard*. And potentially *expensive*. Functional programming just *spits in the face of Computer Science*, whose goal *is* to worry about efficiency. But if you don't want to reply then don't.

Comment: My last comment for now, for future readers (and perhaps for @Doval): Looking over the discussion again, I think there is a confusion I need to clear up. The original question was about making *types* immutable, *not* about making individual variables immutable. My argument has been that that making types immutable *by default* is *not* a good idea because it prevents you from making mutable variables of that type whenever that's necessary (for performance or other reasons). I'm *not* claiming, however, that making *variables* mutable by default is a good idea. So don't confuse the two.

Comment: **Please try to avoid extended discussions in commments.  If you would like to have a discussion then please visit the [Chat Room](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/chat).  Thank you.**

Comment: @Mehrdad "The original question was about making types immutable, not about making individual variables immutable."  Wrong.  The question was about *using* immutable types.  When you assign an immutable type to a variable, you make that specific one immutable.  The OP wants to protect one specific dictionary.  (Doval correctly got my meaning about scalability - it affects code maintainability as much as anything, btw).

Comment: @itsbruce: (I'll only respond since this is a clarification rather than a continuation of the debate, so let's leave it at that.) I guess what I've been trying to say is that the type shouldn't be immutable in the first place, unless it's a violation of the type's correctness rather than a maintainability issue. The user should be able to choose to make individual variables mutable or immutable depending on the situation, and if you make your type immutable, then you take that choice away and force the user to pay an unnecessary performance penalty even when it matters. That's all.

Comment: @Mehrdad Some types can't be made immutable simply by putting them in an immutable reference. Take List in C# or Java or any number of other languages: You can make the reference immutable, but nothing is going to stop you from changing the values at each index, or calling functions to add/remove from it. It's a type that needs to be designed with immutability in mind to be properly immutable when used. Yes, there are trade-offs, but they might not be as bad as you think.

Comment: @Merhdad For example, immutable data structures can do a lot more sharing and a lot less copying than mutable data structures in many cases, because you have a guarantee that no value in one structure will be changed (unexpectedly affecting the value of another structure). This can save performance and memory at runtime. I hear Chris Okasaki's book **Purely Functional Data Structures** is a very good learning resource for this kind of thing.

Comment: @KChaloux: Your first point is just a language limitation, not a conceptual one. I'm not going to continue farther.

Answer (score 23):

Your code should express your intention. If you don't want an object to be modified once created, make it impossible to modify.

Immutability has several benefits:

- **The intention of the original author is expressed better.**

  How would you be able to know that in the following code, modifying the name would cause the application to generate an exception somewhere later?

  ```
  public class Product
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }

      ...
  }
  ```
- **It's easier to make sure that the object wouldn't appear in an invalid state.**

  You have to control this in a constructor, and only there. On the other hand, if you have a bunch of setters and methods which modify the object, such controls may become particularly difficult, especially when, for example, two fields should change at the same time in order for the object to be valid.

  For example, an object is valid if the address is not `null` *or* GPS coordinates are not `null`, but it's invalid if both the address and the GPS coordinates are specified. Can you imagine the hell to validate this if both the address and GPS coordinates have a setter, or both are mutable?
- **Concurrency.**

By the way, in your case, you don't need any third party packages. .NET Framework already includes a [`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: +1, especially for "You have to control this in a constructor, and only there." IMO this is a huge advantage.

Comment: Another benefit: copying an object is free. Just a pointer.

Comment: @MainMa Thank you for your answer, but as far as I understand ReadOnlyDictionary doesn't give any guarantees that someone else will not change the underlying dictionary (even without concurrency I might want to save the reference to the original dictionary within object the method belongs to for later use). ReadOnlyDictionary is even declared in a strange namespace: System.Collections.ObjectModel.

Comment: @RobertGrant Well as free as the memory consumed by keeping a pointer to a memory address. </pedantic>

Comment: @Den: That relates to one of my pet peeves: people regarding "read-only" and "immutable" as synonyms.  If an object is encapsulated in a read-only wrapper *and no other reference exists or is retained anywhere in the universe* then wrapping the object will make it immutable, and a reference to the wrapper may be used as a shorthand to encapsulate the state of the object contained therein.  There is, however, no mechanism by which code can ascertain whether that is the case.  To the contrary, because the wrapper hides the type of the wrapped object, wrapping an immutable object...

Comment: ...will make it impossible for code to know whether the resulting wrapper may be safely considered immutable.

Comment: In the first example, this is a design bug; it should be initialized in the constructor, and there's not reason to even suggest that a setter ought to exist. In the second example, the setters for address and GPS can both clear the other field, guaranteeing that at most one of them will be set, but not necessarily that they're not both null; you'd have to make sure a constructor set one of them from the start, and either log or return an error, or throw if an explicit null was set.

Answer (score 14):

There are many single-threaded reasons to use immutability. For example

Object A contains Object B.

External code queries your Object B and you return it.

Now you have three possible situations:

1. B is immutable, no problem.
2. B is mutable, you make a defensive copy and return that. Performance hit but no risk.
3. B is mutable, you return it.

In the third case the user code may not realize what you have done and may make changes to the object, and by so doing change the internal data of your object with you having no control or visibility of that happening.

Answer (score 11):

Immutability can also greatly simplify the implementation of garbage collectors. From [GHC's wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Memory_Management):

> [...]
>   Data immutability forces us to produce a lot of temporary data but it also helps to collect this garbage rapidly. The trick is that immutable data NEVER points to younger values. Indeed, younger values don't yet exist at the time when an old value is created, so it cannot be pointed to from scratch. And since values are never modified, neither can it be pointed to later. This is the key property of immutable data.
>
> This greatly simplifies garbage collection (GC). At anytime we can scan the last values created and free those that are not pointed to from the same set (of course, real roots of live values hierarchy are live in the stack).
>   [...]
>    So it has a counter-intuitive behavior: the larger percent of your values are garbage - the faster it works. 
>   [...]

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on what [KChaloux](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/250993/127234) summarised very well...

Ideally, you have two types of fields, and hence two types of code using them.  Either fields are immutable, and code doesn't have to take mutability into account; or fields are mutable, and we need to write code that either takes a snapshot (`int x = p.x`) or gracefully handles such changes.

In my experience, most code falls in between the two, being *optimistic* code: it freely references mutable data, assuming that the first call to `p.x` will have the same result as the second call.  And most of the time, this is true, except when it turns out it no longer is.  Oops.

So, really, turn that question around: **What are my reasons for making this mutable**?

- Reducing memory alloc/free?
- Mutable by nature? (e.g. counter)
- Saves modifiers, horizontal noise? (const/final)
- Makes some code shorter/easier? (init default, possibly overwrite after)

Do you write defensive code?  Immutability will save you some copying around.  Do you write optimistic code?  Immutability will spare you the insanity of that weird, impossible bug.

Answer (score 4):

Another benefit of immutability is that it is the first step in rounding up these immutable objects into a pool. Then you can manage them so that you don't create multiple objects that conceptually and semantically represent the same thing. A good example would be Java's String.

It is a well-known phenomenon in linguistic that a few words appear a lot, might appear in other context as well. So instead of creating multiple `String` object, you can use one immutable. But then you need to keep a pool manager to take care of these immutable objects.

This will save you lot of memory.
This is an interesting article to read as well:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law

Answer (score 2):

There are some nice examples here but I wanted to jump in with some personal ones where immutability helped a ton. In my case, I started off designing an immutable concurrent data structure mainly with the hopes of just being able to confidently run code in parallel with overlapping reads and writes and not having to worry about race conditions. There was a talk John Carmack gave that kind of inspired me to do it where he talked about such an idea. It's a pretty basic structure and pretty trivial to implement like this:

[image]

Of course with a few more bells and whistles to it like being able to remove elements in constant time and leave reclaimable holes behind and have blocks get derefed if they become empty and potentially freed for a given immutable instance. But basically to modify the structure, you modify a "transient" version and atomically commit the changes you made to it to get a new immutable copy that doesn't touch the old one, with the new version only creating new copies of the blocks that have to be made unique while shallow copying and reference counting the others.

However, I didn't find it *that* useful for multithreading purposes. After all, there's still the conceptual problem where, say, a physics system applies physics concurrently while a player is trying to move elements around in a world. Which immutable copy of the transformed data do you go with, the one the player transformed or the one the physics system transformed? So I haven't really found a nice and simple solution to this basic conceptual problem except to have mutable data structures which just lock in a smarter way and discourage overlapping reads and writes to the same sections of the buffer to avoid stalling threads. That's something John Carmack seems to have possibly figured out how to solve in his games; at least he talks about it like he can almost see a solution without opening up a car of worms. I haven't gotten as far as him in that regard. All I can see are endless design questions if I tried to just parallelize everything around immutables. I wish I could spend a day picking at his brain since most of my efforts started off with those ideas he threw out.

Nevertheless, I found *enormous* value of this immutable data structure in other areas. I even use it now to store images which is really weird and does make random-access require some more instructions (right shift and a bitwise `and` along with a layer of pointer indirection), but I'll cover the benefits below.

**Undo System**

One of the most immediate places I found to benefit from this was the undo system. Undo system code used to be one of the most error-prone things in my area (visual FX industry), and not just in the products I worked on but in competing products (their undo systems were also flaky) because there were so many different types of data to worry about undoing and redoing properly (property system, mesh data changes, shader changes that weren't property-based like swapping one with the other, scene hierarchy changes like changing the parent of a child, image/texture changes, etc. etc. etc.).

So the amount of undo code required was enormous, often rivaling the amount of code implementing the system for which the undo system had to record state changes. By leaning on this data structure, I was able to get the undo system down to just this:

```
on user operation:
    copy entire application state to undo entry
    perform operation

on undo/redo:
    swap application state with undo entry
```

Normally that code above would be enormously inefficient when your scene data spans gigabytes to copy it in entirety. But this data structure only shallow copies things that weren't changed, and it actually made it cheap enough store an immutable copy of the entire application state. So now I can implement undo systems as easily as the code above and just focus on using this immutable data structure to make copying unchanged portions of the application state cheaper and cheaper and cheaper. Since I started using this data structure, all my personal projects have undo systems just using this simple pattern.

Now there is still some overhead here. Last time I measured it was around 10 kilobytes just to shallow copy the entire application state without making any changes to it (this is independent of scene complexity since the scene is arranged in a hierarchy, so if nothing below the root changes, only the root is shallow copied without having to descend down into the children). That's far from 0 bytes as would be needed for an undo system only storing deltas. But at 10 kilobytes of undo overhead per operation, that's still only a megabyte per 100 user operations. Plus I could still potentially squash that down further in the future if needed.

**Exception-Safety**

Exception-safety with a complex application is no trivial matter. However, when your application state is immutable and you're only using transient objects to try to commit atomic change transactions, then it's inherently exception-safe since if any part of the code throws, the transient is tossed away before giving a new immutable copy. So that trivializes one of the hardest things I've always found to get right in a complex C++ codebase.

Too many people often just use RAII-conforming resources in C++ and think that's enough to be exception-safe. Often it isn't, since a function can generally cause side effects to states beyond the ones local to its scope. You generally need to start dealing with scope guards and sophisticated rollback logic in those cases. This data structure made it so I often don't need to bother with that since the functions aren't causing side effects. They're returning transformed immutable copies of application state instead of transforming the application's state.

**Non-Destructive Editing**

[image]

Non-destructive editing is basically layering/stacking/connecting operations together without touching the original user's data (just input data and output data without touching input). It's typically trivial to implement with a simple image application like Photoshop and might not benefit that much from this data structure since many operations might just want to transform every pixel of the entire image.

However, with non-destructive mesh editing, for example, a lot of operations often want to transform only a part of the mesh. One operation might just want to move some vertices here. Another might just want to subdivide some polygons there. Here the immutable data structure helps a ton in avoiding the need to have to make an entire copy of the entire mesh just to return a new version of the mesh with a small part of it changed.

**Minimizing Side Effects**

With these structures in hand, it also makes it easy to write functions that minimize side effects without incurring a huge performance penalty for it. I've found myself writing more and more functions which just return whole immutable data structures by value these days without incurring side effects, even when that seems a bit wasteful.

For example, typically the temptation to transform a bunch of positions might be to accept a matrix and a list of objects and transform those in a mutable fashion. These days I find myself just returning a new list of objects.

When you have more functions like this in your system that cause no side effects, it definitely makes it easier to reason about the correctness of it as well as test its correctness.

**The Benefits of Cheap Copies**

So anyway, these are the areas where I found the most use out of immutable data structures (or persistent data structures). I also got a bit overzealous initially and made an immutable tree and immutable linked list and immutable hash table, but over time I rarely found as much use for those. I mainly found the most use of the chunky immutable array-like container in the diagram above.

I also still have a lot of code working with mutables (find it a practical necessity at least for low-level code), but the main application state is an immutable hierarchy, drilling down from an immutable scene to immutable components inside of it. Some of the cheaper components are still copied in full, but the most expensive ones like meshes and images use the immutable structure to allow those partial cheap copies of only the parts that needed to be transformed.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, C#, and other similar languages, class-type fields may be used either to identify objects, or to encapsulate values or state in those objects, but the languages make no distinction between such usages.  Suppose a class object `George` has a field of type `char[] chars;`.  That field may encapsulate a character sequence in either:

1. An array which will never be modified, nor exposed to any code that might modify it, but to which outside references may exist.
2. An array to which no outside references exist, but which George may modify freely.
3. An array which is owned by George, but to which there may exist outside views which would be expect to represent George's current state.

Additionally, the variable may, instead of encapsulating a character sequence, encapsulate a live view to a character sequence owned by some other object

If `chars` presently encapsulates the character sequence [w i n d], and George wants `chars` to encapsulate the character sequence [w a n d], there are a number of things George could do:

A. Construct a new array containing the characters [w a n d] and change `chars` to identify that array rather than the old one.

B. Identify somehow a pre-existing character array which will always hold the characters [w a n d] and change `chars` to identify that array rather than the old one.

C. Change the second character of the array identified by `chars` to an `a`.

In case 1, (A) and (B) are safe ways to achieve the desired result.  In case (2), (A) and (C) are safe, but (B) would not be [it wouldn't cause immediate problems, but since George would assume that it has ownership of the array, it would assume that it could change the array at will].  In case (3), choices (A) and (B) would break any outside views, and thus only choice (C) is correct.  Thus, knowing how to modify the character sequence encapsulated by the field requires knowing which semantic type of field it is.

If instead of using a field of type `char[]`, which encapsulates a potentially-mutable character sequence, code has used type `String`, which encapsulates an immutable character sequence, all of the above issues go away.  All fields of type `String` encapsulate a sequence of characters using a sharable object that will never change.  Consequently, if a field of type `String` encapsulates "wind", the only way to make it encapsulate "wand" is to make it identify different object--one which holds "wand".  In cases where code holds the only reference to the object, mutating the object may be more efficient than creating a new one, but any time a class is mutable it is necessary to distinguish among the different ways by which it can encapsulate value.  Personally I think Apps Hungarian should have been used for this (I would consider the four uses of `char[]` to be semantically-distinct types, even though the type system considers them identical--exactly the sort of situation where Apps Hungarian shines), but since it wasn't the easiest way to avoid such ambiguities is to design immutable types that only encapsulate values one way.

Comment: It looks like a reasonable answer, but is a bit hard to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of good answers already. This is just an extra info somewhat specific to .NET. I was digging through old .NET blog posts and found a nice sum-up of
benefits from the point of view of the Microsoft Immutable Collections developers:

> 1. Snapshot semantics, allowing you to share your collections in a way
>      that the receiver can count on never changing.
> 2. Implicit thread-safety in multi-threaded applications (no locks
>      required to access collections).
> 3. Any time you have a class member that accepts or returns a
>      collection type and you want to include read-only semantics in the
>      contract.
> 4. Functional programming friendly.
> 5. Allow modification of a collection during enumeration, while
>      ensuring original collection does not change.
> 6. They implement the same IReadOnly* interfaces that your code already
>      deals with so migration is easy.
>
> If someone hands you a ReadOnlyCollection, an IReadOnlyList, or
>   an IEnumerable the only guarantee is that you can’t change the data
>   – there is no guarantee that the person that handed you the collection
>   won’t change it. Yet, you often need some confidence that it won’t
>   change. These types don’t offer events to notify you when their
>   contents change, and if they do change, might that occur on a
>   different thread, possibly while you’re enumerating its contents? Such
>   behavior would lead to data corruption and/or random exceptions in
>   your application.